# Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string, unable to get data from two databases in a single query

Tags: mysql, database, model-view-controller, pdo, laravel-4

```
class Report extends Eloquent {

protected $connection1 = 'mysql1';
    protected $table1 = 'table1';

protected $connection2 = 'mysql2';
    protected $table2 = 'table2';

public function getdetails() {

$mysql1_conn = DB::connection('mysql1');

$mysql2_conn = DB::connection('mysql2');

$result = $mysql1_conn->table('table1 as t1')
          ->{$mysql2_conn->table('table2 as t2')}
         ->ON('t1.userid' , '=' , 't2.userid')
         ->select('t1.id','t2.name','t1.number','t2.address')
         ->get();

        return $result;
}
}
```

i am getting the ERROR

" Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string "

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a single query using two database connections.

Comment: Is there any wrong in my query syntax
or
there is no way to get the data from the data objects like this type.

Comment: Replace get() with toSql() and have a look at the query that gets generated

Comment: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string
at line

'->{$mysql2_conn->table('table2 as t2')}'

Comment: This code is invalid. What are you trying to achieve? You won't be able to use 2 connections in one query. And $mysql2_conn->table('table2 as t2') returns the query builder, hence the error.